# cdf of $X/(X+Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. uniform

Tags: probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. uniform on $[0,1]$. I am asked to find the cdf of $R=\frac{X}{X+Y}$.

I tried to use the auxiliary variable $S=X+Y$, find the joint pdf and then marginalize, but I am not able to find the support of $(R,S)$.

How would you go to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P\left[R\leq r\right]=\int_{0}^{1}P\left[R\leq r\mid Y=y\right]dy=\int_{0}^{1}P\left[X\leq\frac{ry}{1-r}\right]dy$.

It is evident that $P\left[R\leq0\right]=0$ and $P\left[R\leq1\right]=1$
so we can focus on the $r$ in interval $\left(0,1\right)$.

For $\frac{r}{1-r}\leq1$
or equivalently $r\leq\frac{1}{2}$ this leads to $\frac{r}{1-r}\int_{0}^{1}ydy=\frac{r}{2-2r}$.

For $r>\frac{1}{2}$ this leads to $\frac{r}{1-r}\int_{0}^{\frac{1-r}{r}}ydy+\int_{\frac{1-r}{r}}^{1}dy=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2r}$.

**EDIT**

In a more general context:

If $X,Y$ are independent real-valued random variables and $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
is measurable and nonnegative then

> $Ef\left(X,Y\right)=\int\int f\left(x,y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)dF_{Y}\left(y\right)$.

If you are looking for the CDF of $R=g\left(X,Y\right)$ then you
can define $f$ by $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto1$ if $g\left(x,y\right)\leq z$
and $\left(x,y\right)\mapsto0$ otherwise.

This leads to $Ef\left(X,Y\right)=P\left[Z\leq z\right]$
and $P\left[Z\leq z\mid Y=y\right]=\int f\left(x,y\right)dF_{X}\left(x\right)$
and we find

> $P\left[Z\leq z\right]=\int P\left[Z\leq z\mid Y=y\right]dF_{Y}\left(y\right)$.

This statement is even true if $X,Y$ are *not* independent, but that is another chapter. The method is convenient if $P\left[Z\leq z\mid Y=y\right]$ is easy to find.

Comment: Wow this is impressive. Just to know, when is it convinient to use such a method? I mean, in textbooks (at least in mine) this is not a standard procedure, so what I am asking is if there is some euristic to identify the "right" (most efficient) method or if I need an ad hoc analysis.

Comment: In my edit you find some details. Maybe that can help if you must make a choice. Personally I 'like' conditional probabilities, and use them if possible.

Answer (score 2):

> OP wrote:  Find the cdf of $R = \frac{X}{X+Y}$. How would you go to do that?

How would I go to do that? I would use a computer algebra system to do the nitty gritties for me. In this instance, $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/pdfjointuniform.png))</sub>

Then, the cdf of $R = \frac{X}{X+Y}$ is $P(R \le r)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/cdfxplusyoverx.png))</sub>

where `Prob` is a function from the `mathStatica` package (I am one of the authors) for *Mathematica*. All done.